How can we encourage existing users of cogsci.se to announce the site on Google+?
I shared a little information about the site on Google+. I made sure the link was "Public". However, I imagine other existing users of this site may have both better and different social networks to me.
@ArtemKaznatcheev also suggested to me that there may be quite a few academics on Google+. Obviously, I'm not trying to be spammy, I'm just keen to broadly get the word out to academics, graduate students, and other experts about what the site is about and how it could constitute a great resource.
How can we encourage users to share the link on Google+?
Also, if you have shared the link, perhaps put it in the comments below, so we can get a sense of the reaction and also how you phrased the introduction.

On G+, I advertised the beta proposal and shared links to @BenBrocka's metric question and my neuroplasticity question. I have absolutely no CogSci following (or any other kind) on my G+, so my advertisements are worth little. However, I find that tagging a colleague or friend that might answer or enjoy a question is a great way to recruit new members.

We could start by listing all relevant sources in a publicly maintained list as a faq post.
You started doing that here and here. Ben Brocka listed a few here. I suggest we create a new faq post, tailored to the purpose of concisely guiding users in where to post, what to post, and how to go about this respectfully.
